# How to convert Javascript's math functions to a math equation?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

How to generates MathJax formula from JavaScript's math functions? It doesn't need to evaluate the math equation, it just converts the string to a math equation for viewing purpose.

Example the following string `Math.pow(2,3)` outputs to 2<sup>2</sup>

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. See [help], Point #4

Comment: that particular one wouldn't be hard to convert, but what's the limit, or what other operation would you expect to support?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a nice wrapped-up way to do this - you would need to tackle each one in turn.

Comment: Are you trying to turn the code into a mathjax formula or image? To do that reliably, you'll need a table of what calls map to what symbols, and a full-on JS parser to accurately find them.

Comment: @ssube yes, that might be a good way to do it. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [math.js](http://mathjs.org) to parse an expression and convert it to Tex, which can be used to render a MathJax equation.

Here is an online example:
http://mathjs.org/examples/browser/pretty_printing_with_mathjax.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there exists a turnkey library for this, but it is not so hard to do what you want.

1. You can use an existing arithmetic expression parser: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/08/math-evaluator-in-javascript-part1.html
2. You generate from the parse tree MathML code :http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML
3. then there exist tools for viewing MathML like Mathjax: http://www.mathjax.org/